# Docker multi-node vs one node in cluster

Tags: docker

I am a little new with the concept of docker and containerization. What I want is to deploy multiple DataBases like MongoDB, Elassandra, ... in one cloud service.

As it mentioned in [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/) link, we can create multiple VMs using the following command in Docker CLI:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox <virtualbox-name>
```

> So, my question is which of the following approaches performance is better in one cloud implementation:
>
> 1. To have one node at all
> 2. To have multiple node in cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely have multiple nodes in the cluster.

Having single node will results into single point of failure. if the node is down then your database is not accessible and would affect the users connected to the database.

Comment: maybe we can handle the problem you've mentioned by scaling the application. For example `docker stack deploy .... scale <number>`

Comment: where do you deploy the replicas? on same node?

Comment: Can we use `docker swarm` or this one instead of `Kubernetes`?

Comment: You can use either one. Swarm is easy compared to kubernetes